# integrating svnant with ant 1.6 and svnclient1.7

Tags: ant, tortoisesvn, svnant

Is svnant 1.3 version compatible to use with my svnclient version 1.7?

I need to integrate svnclient with my ant script to get latest sources.

Answer (score 2):

svnant 1.4 now supports subversion 1.7, but you need to build it yourself.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174056/1303568).

Answer (score 1):

The latest svnant [release](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) is 1.3.1, which is for Subversion 1.6. It doesn't look like there's about to be a new release anytime soon.

You'll need to update svnClientAdapter.jar and svnjavahl.jar in order for svnant to work with 1.7.