# svnant does not support svn version 1.7. what to do?

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I'm using tortoise svn, and recently I updated to version 1.7. Still, in our build system (ant script) we use svnant lib (to get current revision number, we use it as version number). So can no longer build the project as svnant does not support 1.7 version of svn. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the command line version of svn.

1. [Download](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) and Install it on your machine
2. Include it in your Path (so that you can execute svn from the command line)
3. Change the svnsettings to

   ```
   <svnSetting
       svnkit="false"
       javahl="false"
       id="svn.settings"/>
   ```

`svnant` will then use the command line version to do all svn things.

Comment: ,thank you! and is it possible somehow to specify location instead of puting it to path?

Comment: according to [the offical guide](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) it is not.

Comment: ,may I ask one more stupid question: where should I place svnSetting node?

Comment: I prefer to put it after the typedef for the svnant library, so that it is executed right away

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of svnkit (pure Java lib) is compatible with Subversion 1.7.
http://svnkit.com/download.php

You can download the standalone version and copy the libs from folder lib to your classpath. You need at least the last 5 jars.

```
<path id="path.svnant">
    <pathelement location="svnant/svnant.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/svnClientAdapter.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/ganymed.jar" />

    <pathelement location="svnant/svnkit-1.7.8.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/svnkit-javahl16-1.7.8.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/sqljet-1.1.6.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar" />
    <pathelement location="svnant/sequence-library-1.0.2.jar" />
</path>
```

Answer (score 6):

svnant has now been updated in the source to support SVN 1.7, but you'll need to build it yourself.

In a command prompt:

1. Check out svnant into a local directory (username guest, empty password):

   > svn co http://subclipse.tigris.org/svn/subclipse/trunk/svnant/ svnant --username=guest
2. CD into the root svnant directory
3. Build:

   > ant makeDistrib
4. Copy the built files from build\distrib\lib into your ANT lib folder (probably C:\Program Files\Ant\lib or C:\Program Files (x86)\Ant\lib)

The inline properties such as svnkit="false" are now deprecated, so you will need to update to use svnSetting as described in [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558376/1303568).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to svnant is [svntask](https://github.com/opticyclic/svntask)

I have just recently forked it from [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/p/svntask/) and updated it to work with svn 1.7.

It doesn't contain as many commands as svnant but contains the basics such as getting the version number.